# Neo4j matching nodes based on multiple criteria

Tags: graph, neo4j

We are using Neo4j to find best-matches for a speed-dating type of conference. Prior to the conference each Person fills out a form that specifies:

1. Languages (one or more)
2. Location (one to five preferred)
3. Interests (one to five interests)

We've ingested the data into Neo4j such that People, Languages, Locations, and Interests are all node types. The labels on the nodes represent the literal values e.g. (Person:Dave)->[r:knows]->(Language:English).

We would like to iterate through all Person nodes and find all matches to other Person nodes who have the same Language and Location and Interests.

In pseudocode: Languages(English||Spanish) && Location (Maryland||DC||Virginia) && Interests(Books||Movies||Food||Sports)

I'm pretty new to Cypher so I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Match (p:Person) with p  
// skip 0 limit 1000 -optional if you have big data 
Match (p)-[r:SPEAKS]->(l:Language)<-[r2:SPEAKS]-(p2:Person), 
(p)-[r3:LIVES]->(l:Location)<-[r4:LIVES]-(p2), 
(p)-[r5:LIKES]->(l:Interest)<-[r6:LIKES]-(p2) 
where id(p) < id(p2) 
Return distinct p, p2
```

You might use different way to exclude duplicates (id(p) < id(p2) ) as it woun't work with limit

Comment: Sorry that's it's been a while but this worked really well. I had a 1-week old at the time so I forgot to respond.